# Is my logic right for my hiding button, I'm trying to not show one of my options

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, button, hide

Getting started on JavaScript here. So I want to hide one of 3 choices(tabs I have), I currently have 3 tabs. 
Chase, Wells Fargo, Bank of America. I have a choice of arguments from 0 to 7(carriers), if a client choose carrier 7 I want to to disable the Wells Fargo tab so the payment won't go through.

This is my logic:

```
    if (carrier = '7')

 }
  hide cash button?
```

My fragment of JavaScript

```
function pickChoices(carrier,loc,acct){
     if(typethe acct == 'undefined'){ // third party not passed in (from carrier select box)
        if(!opts.isRetail){
           if( $("#useMyAccount" + loc).css("display") != "none")
              acct = ($("#thirdParty" + loc + ":checked").val() != null) // pull value from checkbox
           else
              acct = false;
        }else{
           acct = false;
        }
     }
     vGoCheckout = false;
     formObj.action.value = "pickChoice";
     formObj.mode.value = loc;
     var vData = $(formObj).gogoTokenSerialize();
     $.whse.ajaxPost(url_ + '&content=json&' + vData, 'POST', null, selectCarrierCallback, null, 'json', true);
   }
```

Comment: `typethe` should be `typeof`

Comment: Where are you testing if they chose 7?

Comment: Thanks sir, can you give some tips on answer? My entire code is too long here, I think I posted the right part.

Comment: I don't understand what you've posted at all.

Comment: There's nothing here that disables a specific tab. It doesn't seem to be related to your question at all.

Comment: You don't have to post your entire code. Boil it down to something that just demonstrates the part related to the question.

Comment: That's not how this site works. You post the question here, so that everyone can see it and help, and other people can learn from it.

Comment: entire code is way too long, I'm trying to find the right function now

Comment: That's why I said to post a [mcve].